# 'Concatenate' a struct into a char array

Tags: c, casting, struct, concatenation

I have a struct that's used in my internet application, which looks like:

```
struct query {
     ushort trans_id;
     ushort flags;
     ushort opcode;
     ushort content_length;
     char content[512];
};
```

Basically, I'm just trying to take this structure and turn it into a "packet" to be sent. It must have the corresponding length and everything. So; if I could I would have like:
struct query q;

```
q.trans_id = 0x5544;
q.flags = 0x0000;
q.opcode = 0x0010;
q.content_length = 0x0001;
q.content[0] = '\0'; //I would want my packet to end up looking like this, when outputted to the socket:
//\x55\x44\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x01\x00
//and yes, it's going to be stored in a char buffer, but I'm not using any functions that will trim off any of the things past the null!
```

I feel like it's a relatively simple question that can probably be answered by casting my data types, but I think it's a bit harder than that.

I also did try using sprintf, but it would turn my nulls into actual 0s, so 0x0000 would become 2 '0' ASCII characters!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can indeed simply cast the pointer to your struct to a char *, such as:

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* for size_t */

....

struct query q;
/* fill in the struct ... */
char *packet = (char *)(&q);
size_t packet_size = sizeof(struct query);
```

If you want the packet size to trim the content of the query struct, you'll have to calculate the difference (by using strnlen for example on the content and subtracting the difference)

EDIT: Alternatively for trimming you can do:

```
int packet_size = (&(q.content[0]) + strnlen(q.content, 512)) - &q;
```

Comment: What happens when this is sent to a machine that uses different padding or endianness?

Comment: I think this post was very helpful; it DID accomplish what I wanted. I should (REALLY) brush up on my pointers. Thanks.

Comment: detly, yes, but that's a different issue (network interoperability). I answered the question of how to create a buffer from a struct.

Comment: @Saustin, @sinelaw - actually, it doesn't necessarily accomplish what you want (ie. how you want your packet to look, exact length), although that depends on machine architecture. If you try this on various machines, you'll get extra unpredictable bytes between fields and a machine-dependent length.

Comment: @detly: It accomplishes what @saustin said he wanted, namely sending a structure as a 'packet'. Portability problems due to endian-ness, struct packing,  word sizes are worth mentioning, but may be irrelevant to him.

Comment: @Roddy - the idea of "sending" something as a "packet" makes absolutely no sense unless you consider the destination. It's not just about portability either, it's about the next time he compiles the same program with a different set of flags or pragmas.

Comment: It accomplishes what I wanted, however eventually I would need to do what cnicutar was talking about; for example in the DNS RFC they specify domains in a very weird way (replacing the "dots" with the lengths of the pertruding subdomain), and it is very vital to know "where you are" in the buffer, so if you can't find the length, you're basically screwed. I only chose sinelaw's answer because it did what I wanted; the content buffer is at the very end of the string so I don't have to worry too much.

Comment: @Saustin - I'm being pedantic about it because I've been at the other end of this kind of crappy serialisation code: having to decipher seemingly random bytes stored in EEPROM in a system that suddenly stopped working after a simple, unrelated code change; all because the original developer wrote fragile code years before that happened to "work for him." Compiling it on *the same compiler*, but with a different flag, made it break.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to send it as a packet you need to be careful about endianness (`htons`). Make your own function that creates the "packet".

- Create a large-enough buffer (a static char array should do fine)
- Copy (`memcpy`) each element into it. Don't forget about `htons`

You might be tempted to just `write` the `struct` to the socket. **You shouldn't do this**, as there's no guarantee that the layout of the fields will be the same on the receiving machine (padding?).

Comment: Ah yes! I stumble with "endianness".. Thank you very much for the heads up.